# Remove window from taskbar on Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, windows-10, taskbar

I want to remove window from taskbar on Windows 10 with multiple desktops.
For Windows 8.1 i used ITaskbarList::DeleteTab and it works excellent.

For Windows 10 this method hides Windows from taskbar too, but after it i see this window on all desktops. I want to see this window only on one desktop.

Does anyone know the method to hide window from task bar in Windows 10 and stay this window on one desktop?

Below you can see, what i meant under "hide window from task bar in Windows 10":

[image]

Comment: what is *"hide window from task bar in Windows 10 and stay this window on one desktop"*" supposed to mean? Could you rephrase that?

Comment: Thank you, i will try to add image.

Comment: Thats window preview.

Comment: .... and thats a windows configuration option, nothing to "remove" here unless you want to manipulate windows settings. This smells like a request for malware creation-assistance.

Comment: Oh no, i do not develop malware. In my case it is something like tool window, but in my case it is a separate window. And it is not cool if user see tool window in task bar. For now i tried to hide using IVirtualDesktopManager it if user changes current desktop. But if there is a method to hide it in task bar, it will be more suitable solution.

Comment: Its not possible to hide a seperate window from the taskbar **if** the user chose to display them ungrouped. Thats how Microsoft Windows works. If you want to have them count as one window you need to create the second window as child of the first, the parameter *hWndParent* will do that : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632679(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Yes i know, but i cannot use child window. It is specific of my app. You say "Its not possible to hide a seperate window from the taskbar if the user chose to display them ungrouped", but this method do it ITaskbarList::DeleteTab. And for Windows 8.1 it works very well.

Comment: IIRC one method of doing it is to make your window a child of a hidden window.

Comment: It is rather odd that you have a window with the title "ConsoleApplication1". Console applications don't have regular windows, they have consoles. So either you are intentionally trying to trick us, or this is a confusing accident brought about by initially creating a console application and then changing the subsystem to Windows without changing the app's name.

Comment: @specializt I believe you are thinking of an *owned*/*owner* window relationship, rather than a child/parent window relationship. Very different things. Top-level windows cannot be children, but they can be owned. Which solves the problem here.

Comment: correct - indeed i mixed that up **but** parent of *window A* is **by default** also owner of *window A*, as is stated in the documentation of [SetOwner](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f1b6ts6.aspx)

Comment: @specializt Indeed it does say that, but confusingly that is documentation is talking about MFC ownership, not Win32 ownership. And regrettably, the Win32 SDK documentation often uses the terms interchangeably because the same function entrypoint is used to set the parent or owner. That works because a single window can have *either* a parent *or* an owner (depending on if it's a child window or a top-level window), *not both*. Raymond Chen blogged about this a while back; highly recommended reading to clear up the confusion: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100315-00/?p=14613

Comment: @CodyGray I simple create console template in VS. But tell the truth i do not use only WinAPI, i used Qt. But i use HWND of Qt window to call API and so on. Thanks msdn article is useful.

Comment: mixing APIs is **always** a bad idea unless its officially supported by both. You will run into trouble. Just sayan. This is the main reason for OSS software on windows always being unstable or very buggy - bascially, the OSS community decided to re-invent MS-API in parts ... which is bound to fail at some point, either use a MS-supported API or ... install gentoo :-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my understanding, borne out by my empirical tests, the windows that appear in the taskbar previews are exactly the same windows that would ordinarily appear in the taskbar. A long time ago, say in Windows 2000, each of an application's eligible windows would just appear as buttons on the taskbar. Starting in Windows XP, taskbar grouping became an option, so that all eligible windows from a single application could be grouped together and appear as a single button on the taskbar. Then, in Windows Vista, it became possible to display previews of these open windows when you hovered over the corresponding taskbar button. Neither Windows 8 nor Windows 10 changed that fundamental rule; they only changed the appearance of the previews.

As such, we can refer back to the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969325.aspx#Managing_Taskbar_But) for the rules about which windows appear on the taskbar:

> The Shell creates a button on the taskbar whenever an application creates a window that isn't owned. To ensure that the window button is placed on the taskbar, create an unowned window with the `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` extended style. To prevent the window button from being placed on the taskbar, create the unowned window with the `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW` extended style. As an alternative, you can create a hidden window and make this hidden window the owner of your visible window.

Raymond Chen has summarized these rules more precisely [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031229-00/?p=41283). Quoting him:

> There are some basic rules on which windows go into the taskbar. In short:
>
> - If the `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` extended style is set, then it will show (when visible).
> - If the window is a top-level unowned window, then it will show (when visible).
> - Otherwise it doesn't show.
>
> (Though the [ITaskbarList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774652.aspx) interface muddies this up a bit.)

You were muddying it up before, calling `ITaskbarList::DeleteTab`. That is not necessary. To ensure that a window does not appear in the taskbar, just apply the converse of the rules governing when a window *does* appear in the taskbar.

If you have a top-level unowned window, it will be shown in the taskbar unless you *remove* the `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` extended window style. If you have an owned window, then it will *not* be shown in the taskbar unless the `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` extended window style is set to force it there.

So if you have the `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` extended window style set, you should remove it. That is forcing the window to be displayed in the taskbar.

Otherwise, you should set an owner for your window. For example, make the second window be owned by the first.

Comment: Thanks you answer and comment about parent/owner of window was realy useful. I found where was my mistake. I leave one remark here about Qt specific, because it can be usefull for something. If you want create QWidget with owner (non with parent) you need to pass parent and set window flags in constructor of QWidget (ex Qt::Window, Qt::Tool). If you call setParent and setWidnwoFlags after construcor, it set parent (non-owner) to window.

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR:**

1. Remove both `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` and `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW` from the extended style.
2. Set an owner for the window.

---

**Example:**

Removing flags from the extended style:

```
SetWindowLong(myHWND, GWL_EXSTYLE, 
    GetWindowLong(myHWND, GWL_EXSTYLE) & ~WS_EX_APPWINDOW & ~WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW);
```

Setting an owner:

```
SetWindowLongPtr(myHWND, GWLP_HWNDPARENT, myOwnerHWND);
```

---

**Full explanation:**

Despite [Cody's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37772695/4213607) being great, it does not quite answer the exact question.

The exact question is: "How to display a window that does not appear in the taskbar, *yet appears only on one virtual desktop*?

As Cody explained, there are several ways to remove the taskbar button for a window. However, there is only **one** way among them that makes it display on only one virtual desktop at the same time.

If you include the flag `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` in your extended style, it will force the window to show in the taskbar. That's why it must be cleared in this case.

If you include the flag `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW` in your extended style, it will force the window **not** to show in the taskbar, **but** will force the window to be shown on all virtual desktops. Thus it's not an option either here.

Finally, if your window has neither flags, it will show in the taskbar if and only if it does not have an owner. Either way, it will **not** force itself on all virtual desktops. Hence, the solution is to have neither flags but to set an owner.

Answer (score 0):

Add **WS_EX_NOACTIVATE** to the ex styles of the window.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/extended-window-styles

> A top-level window created with this style does not become the
> foreground window when the user clicks it. The system does not bring
> this window to the foreground when the user minimizes or closes the
> foreground window. The window should not be activated through
> programmatic access or via keyboard navigation by accessible
> technology, such as Narrator. To activate the window, use the
> SetActiveWindow or SetForegroundWindow function. The window does not
> appear on the taskbar by default. To force the window to appear on the
> taskbar, use the WS_EX_APPWINDOW style.